# how to extract lines which have no duplicated values in first column?

Tags: awk, vim, duplicates

For some statistics research, I want to separate my data which have duplicated value in first column. I work with vim.

suppose that a part of my data is like this:

```
Item_ID   Customer_ID
  123          200
  104          134
  734          500
  123          345
  764          347
  1000         235
  734          546
```

as you can see, some lines have equal values in first column,

i want to generate two separated files, which one of them contains just non repeated values and the other contains lines with equal first column value.

for above example i want to have these two files:
first one contains:

```
Item_ID   Customer_ID
  123          200
  734          500
  123          345
  734          546
```

and second one contains:

```
Item_ID   Customer_ID
  104          134
  764          347
  1000         235
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you thought about awk? e.g. `awk '{a[$1]++} a[$1] == 1' file.txt > out1.txt` && `awk '{a[$1]++} a[$1] > 1' file.txt > out2.txt`

Comment: @peterrincker thank you Peter. but this is not work correctly. as a test, i ran it over my example, but it just separate duplicated values in separate files. it means that, as an example, Item_ID=123 occures two and your awk separate each one in a file. but I want to have all duplicated Item_ID's in one file and another file contains  just unique Item_ID's. this is which i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR>1{a[$1]++;b[NR]=$1;c[NR]=$2} END {for (i=2;i<=NR;i++) print b[i],c[i] > (a[b[i]]==1?"single":"multiple")}' file

cat single
104 134
764 347
1000 235

cat multiple
123 200
734 500
123 345
734 546
```

PS I skipped the first line, but it could be implemented.

This way you get one file for single hits, one for double, one for triple etc.

```
awk 'NR>1{a[$1]++;b[NR]=$1;c[NR]=$2} END {for (i=2;i<=NR;i++) print b[i],c[i] > "file"a[b[i]]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think awk would be a better option here.

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR { seen[$1]++; next } seen[$1] == 1' input.txt input.txt > uniq.txt
$ awk 'FNR == NR { seen[$1]++; next } seen[$1] > 1' input.txt input.txt > dup.txt
```

Prettier version of awk code:

```
FNR == NR {
    seen[$1]++;
    next
}
seen[$1] == 1
```

#### Overview

We loop over the text twice. By supplying the same file to our awk script twice we are effectively looping over the text twice. First time though the loop count the number of times we see our field's value. The second time though the loop output only the records which have a field value count of `1`. For the duplicate line case we only output lines which have field value counts greater than 1.

#### Awk primer

`awk` loops over lines (or records) in a text file/input and splits each line into fields. `$1` for the first field, `$2` for the second field, etc. By default fields are separated by whitespaces (this can be configured).

`awk` runs each line through a series of rules in the form of `condition { action }`. Any time a `condition` matches then `action` is taken.

Example of printing the first field which line matches `foo`:

```
awk '/foo/ { print $1 }` input.txt
```

#### Glory of Details

Let's take a look at finding only the unique lines which the first field only appears once.

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR { seen[$1]++; next } seen[$1] == 1' input.txt input.txt > uniq.txt
```

Prettier version for readability:

```
FNR == NR {
    seen[$1]++;
    next
}
seen[$1] == 1
```

- `awk 'code' input > output` - run `code` over the input file, `input`, and then redirect the output to file, `output`
- `awk` can take more than one input. e.g. `awk 'code' input1.txt input2.txt`.
- Use the same input file, `input.txt`, twice to loop over the input twice
- `awk 'FNR == NR { code1; next } code2' file1 file2` is a common awk idiom which will run `code1` for `file1` and run `code2` for `file2`
- `NR` is the current record (line) number. This increments after each record
- `FNR` is the current file's record number. e.g. `FNR` will be `1` for the first line in each file
- `next` will stop executing any more actions and go to the next record/line
- `FNR == NR` will only be true for the first file
- `$1` is the first field's data
- `seen[$1]++` - `seen` is an array/dictionary where we use the first field, `$1`, as our key and increment the value so we can get a count
- `$0` is the entire line
- `print ...` prints out the given fields
- `print $0` will print out the entire line
- just `print` is short for `print $0`
- `condition { print $0 }` can be shorted to `condition { print }` which can be shorted further to just `condition`
- `seen[$1] == 1` which check to see if the first field's value count is equal to `1` and print the line

Comment: This is a great answer, but unfortunately it doesn't explain what the script does and how it works... Including an explanation here would improve the answer immensely.

Answer (score 0):

That would require some filtering of the list of lines in the buffer. If you're really into statistics research, I'd go search for a tool that is better suited than a general-purpose text editor, though.

That said, my [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) has some commands that can do the job:

```
:2,$DeleteUniqueLinesIgnoring /\s\+\d\+$/
:w first
:undo
:2,$DeleteAllDuplicateLinesIgnoring /\s\+\d\+$/
:w second
```

As you want to filter on the first column, the commands' `/{pattern}/` has to filter out the second column; `\s\+\d\+$` matches the final number and its preceding whitespace.

`:DeleteUniqueLinesIgnoring` (from the plugin) gives you just the duplicates, `:DeleteAllDuplicateLinesIgnoring` just the unique lines. I simply `:write` them to separate files and `:undo` in between.